# Fetching images from Document Directory

Tags: ios, swift

Hi guys I want to fetch all images from document and append them in cell.

I created this function to save images on didSelectItemAt

```
 func saveImage(image: UIImage, imageName: String) {

    let path = "yourProjectImages"
       let document = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent(path, isDirectory: true)



        let imageUrl = document!.appendingPathComponent("\(imageName).jpg", isDirectory: true)

        do {

                try UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.write(to: imageUrl, options: .atomic)
            } catch {

            print(error.localizedDescription)


            }

        }
```

I used it as I said in didSelectItemAt

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


let selectedImage = images[indexPath.item]

saveImage(image: selectedImage, imageName: "\(selectedImage)")


}
```

[it seems to add picture immediately in document after clicking on the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylsf4.png)

But how to fetch them all in HomeFeed which is my rootController?

These showed photos is album I used Photos framework to fetch multiple photos from album.

Comment: I have no idea what the issue is here, can you try to explain a bit better? your code shows how to save an image, not fetch it. the image shows all of the images displayed in a collection cell? so where is the issue? you seem to be able to save items and retrieve them?

Comment: I want to fetch all saved images and  present them in other viewController , that collectionView that you can see from link  are photos from album I used Photos framework to fetch multiple photos , when user cliks on photos from album they are saved in document but I want to fetch all that saved  photos in other viewController

Comment: At least the option `isDirectory: true` of `appendingPathComponent` is wrong. The URL is definitely not a directory. Omit the `isDirectory` parameter.

Comment: Does anybody knows the solution?